# Django ContentType and generic relationship

Tags: python, django

I need a proper and detailed explanation and understanding of how Django content type model works and the use and purposes of generic relationships. I am trying to create an anonymous chatting app where users can come and register and other people can send them messages whether registered or not through a link the user created and they would not know who sent it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just need an explanation on how and where to use django content type and generic relationships

Comment: Finally, I would love some amazing ideas and insight on how to go about the project i stated earier